# Canvas in Java: problem with color superposition

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas

I have a loop on a canvas where sometimes some different colors can be applied to the same pixel. For example, my loop will do :

```
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 0.5f, redPaint);
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 0.5f, blackPaint);
```

The problem when I do that is that I get a mix between red and white (a kind of brown), and not a red color. When I have several colors applied to the same pixel, I would like this pixel to be of the color or the last color applied, not a mixed color.

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably have the blending mode wrong. Use source over. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode

Comment: check alpha channel of colors